# HTML parsing , nested div issue using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract specific nested div class and the corresponding h3 attribute (salary value).

So, I have tried the search by class method

```
soup.find_all('div',{'class':"vac_display_field"}
```

which returns an empty list.

Snippet code:

```
 <div class="vac_display_field">
      <h3>
       Salary
      </h3>
      <div class="vac_display_field_value">
       Â£27,951 - Â£30,859
      </div>
 </div>
```

Example [here](https://www.civilservicejobs.service.gov.uk/csr/index.cgi?SID=cGFnZWNsYXNzPUpvYnMmb3duZXJ0eXBlPWZhaXImY3NvdXJjZT1jc3FzZWFyY2gmcGFnZWFjdGlvbj12aWV3dmFjYnlqb2JsaXN0JnNlYXJjaF9zbGljZV9jdXJyZW50PTEmdXNlcnNlYXJjaGNvbnRleHQ9MjczMzIwMTcmam9ibGlzdF92aWV3X3ZhYz0xNTEyMDAwJm93bmVyPTUwNzAwMDAmcmVxc2lnPTE0NzcxNTIyODItYjAyZmM4ZTgwNzQ2ZTA2NmY5OWM0OTBjMTZhMWNlNjhkZDMwZDU4NA==)

Comment: You code is fine, are you sure you init the soup right? with the right html?

Comment: Add your code to the question, it may be how you are getting the source that is the problem. Also the salary is not in the h3 and you have obvious encoding issues

Comment: The text `Salary` is, the actual salary is not

Comment: @mangoHero1, *and the corresponding h3 attribute (**salary value**)*. The OP has also not provided an mcve http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so there is no answer to their question as we have no idea what libs they are using, what version of BeautifulSoup or basically anything about their code.

Answer (score -1):

First make sure you've instantiated your `BeautifulSoup` object correctly. Should look something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.civilservicejobs.service.gov.uk/csr/index.cgi?SID=cGFnZWNsYXNzPUpvYnMmb3duZXJ0eXBlPWZhaXImY3NvdXJjZT1jc3FzZWFyY2gmcGFnZWFjdGlvbj12aWV3dmFjYnlqb2JsaXN0JnNlYXJjaF9zbGljZV9jdXJyZW50PTEmdXNlcnNlYXJjaGNvbnRleHQ9MjczMzIwMTcmam9ibGlzdF92aWV3X3ZhYz0xNTEyMDAwJm93bmVyPTUwNzAwMDAmcmVxc2lnPTE0NzcxNTIyODItYjAyZmM4ZTgwNzQ2ZTA2NmY5OWM0OTBjMTZhMWNlNjhkZDMwZDU4NA=='
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser') # the 'html.parser' part is optional.
```

Your code used to scrape the `div` tags looks correct (it's missing a closing parentheses, however). If, for some reason it still hasn't worked, try calling your `find_all()` method in this way:

```
soup.find_all('div', class_='vac_display_field')
```

If you look at the page's code, upon inspecting you'll find that the `div` tag you need is the second from the top:

[image: Xpath]

Thus, your code can reflect that, using simple index notation:

```
Salary_info = soup.find_all(class_='vac_display_field')[1]
```

Then output the text:

```
for info in Salary_info:
    print info.get_text()
```

HTH.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham So that's why you downvoted my answer? If and when he does provide his attempted code, I understood what he wanted quite clearly, although the wording was slightly off. He can then adjust his code accordingly

Comment: *So, I have tried the search by class* method `soup.find_all('div',{'class':"vac_display_field"}` *which **returns an empty list.*** So can you explain how `soup.find_all('div', class_='vac_display_field')` will work where `soup.find_all('div',{'class':"vac_display_field"}` does not?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You're misinterpreting my answer. The way the `find_all()` method is called does not make a difference but that's there to say there *is* another way to call it. Reread the part at the top. The first thing I stressed was that the `soup` needed to be correctly instantiated. I then proceeded to show how to get desired output. And may I once again reiterate: you need to **close the parentheses on your method call**.